# Can't find menu? I need it to connect to my wireless internet

Tags: wireless, 12.10, menu, dell-mini-9

In Ubuntu help (12.10) it just tells me to go to 'menu'. I can't find 'menu' and so therefore I can't connect to my wifi. I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 off of a usb and I don't know how to connect to the internet.

Comment: See [My WiFi adapter is not working at all. Where to start troubleshooting?](http://askubuntu.com/q/235279/88802). Please update your question with the results from that post.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, goto " System Settings" on the taskbar. Next, click on network, and then, you should see "Wireless". Click on it and slide from off to on at the top right hand corner.

Comment: It doesn't give me the option of 'Wireless', just 'Wired' and 'Network proxy'

Comment: I believe that you don't have a driver installed. Please find out which hardware (wireless) you are using and temporarily download a package from this site : http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers
Please read this too : https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/troubleshooting-wireless.html