# how to have internet acess by wifi in Ubuntu 12.10 (Fujitsu LH 532)?

Tags: fujitsu-siemens

I am a newcomer on Ubuntu and I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 but i cannot turn on wifi to have internet access.What can i do to let wifi works?sorry for my bad english.

Comment: it may be a hardware or a software issue. do you have a separate hardware button that works? please explain what do you mean by "cannot turn on wifi".

Comment: Is your wireless card recognized? If not, start here: [My WiFi adapter is not working at all. Where to start troubleshooting?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-where-to-start-troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [Wireless troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html)

Comment: Is that even complete? That page seems not to be updated for 12.10 and containing only useless content now.

Comment: @gertvdijk I have updated the link and that should be his first reference to start troubleshoot.

Comment: Please quote some parts which could be useful for op. Links die...

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen Sorry but the input from op is very few and so thought to refer him for the official documentation.