# How can I get wireless to work on a Dell Latitude D610?

Tags: wireless

I cannot log into my wifi on my dell latitude.

I have to hard wire it to my other laptop to get on the Internet. Does anyone have any idea about how to get the wifi to work?

```
john@john-Latitude-D610:~$ rfkill list all
john@john-Latitude-D610:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_seq_dummy          12686  0 
bnep                   17707  2 
rfcomm                 37276  0 
bluetooth             183228  10 bnep,rfcomm
b43                   347284  0 
snd_intel8x0           33106  2 
snd_ac97_codec        105616  1 snd_intel8x0
radeon                820734  3 
joydev                 17161  0 
ac97_bus               12670  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm                80163  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec
mac80211              461161  1 b43
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
ttm                    75534  1 radeon
snd_rawmidi            25382  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51255  3 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
drm_kms_helper         47303  1 radeon
drm                   238768  5 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
cfg80211              175375  2 b43,mac80211
snd_timer              24411  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14137  4 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    61991  11 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
gpio_ich               13159  0 
dell_laptop            17161  0 
pcmcia                 39509  0 
soundcore              14599  1 snd
psmouse                84843  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 radeon
bcma                   34483  1 b43
snd_page_alloc         14036  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
microcode              18209  0 
serio_raw              13031  0 
dcdbas                 14054  1 dell_laptop
lpc_ich                16925  0 
yenta_socket           27095  0 
pcmcia_rsrc            18191  1 yenta_socket
ppdev                  12817  0 
mac_hid                13037  0 
pcmcia_core            21505  3 pcmcia,yenta_socket,pcmcia_rsrc
parport_pc             31968  1 
video                  18847  0 
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40753  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
ssb                    50087  1 b43
tg3                   130448  0
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: What have you tried apart from the commands there? List obvious actions like "applied all updates", "tried version x.y of Ubuntu too". Anyway, it seems your radio killswitch isn't detected (or not present). Try some options here: [My WiFi adapter is not working at all. Where to start troubleshooting?](http://askubuntu.com/q/235279/88802)

Answer (score 1):

With the ethernet connected, please do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

Detach the ethernet and your wireless should be working.

Comment: popped up said disconnected you are now off line

Comment: had this problem with windows 7 but went in the settings and pulled up available wireless connections and it worked switched to ubuntu and the problem is back must be the laptop itself

Comment: shows up in my network connections now yay but cant turn it on

Comment: any advise @chili555 you seen to be on the right track i go to network connections and wireless is there and airplaine  mode is on i turn it off but still cant turn on the wifi close out come back airplane is back on

Comment: As an experiment, try: sudo modprobe -r dell-laptop; sudo rfkill unblock all. Now is airplane mode off? Now can you connect?

Comment: @chilil555 nope

Comment: Does the Fn+F2 wireless key combination change the wireless LED? With dell-laptop removed, does rfkill list all list anything new?

Comment: the fn f2 turned it on nice call still dont show the simble but it connected

Comment: i tried it before you sent me the info and it didnt work wasnt showing wireless connection at all thanks for your help whoop whoop@chili555

Comment: having the same problem with xbuntu and lubuntu none of the above worked on them

Comment: @JohnHartel- Do you have the exact same wireless device as the OP? If not, please specify in your own new question. We'll be glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

try this and its works for me for my dell 5220

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=62666

Comment: Several things are wrong here. 1) on different hardware 2) link-only 3) Not clear to what part of the page you're referring to 4) Arch Linux isn't Ubuntu ---- Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.