# RTL8111/8168B Rev 06 Ethernet controller not working with AMD64 Kernels > 2.6

Tags: drivers, ethernet, realtek, wired

I'm also having trouble with the RTL8111 Ethernet controller. It's not working at all on Ubuntu x64.

This is my card:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
```

I tested it with following amd64 versions:

```
Mint 16          | Kernel 3.11 | r8169 & r8168 not working
Debian 7.2       | Kernel 3.2  | r8169 & r8168 not working
Ubuntu 13.10     | Kernel 3.11 | r8169 & r8168 not working
Ubuntu 12.04.3   | Kernel 3.8  | r8169 & r8168 not working
Ubuntu 12.04.2   | Kernel 3.5  | r8169 & r8168 not working
Ubuntu 12.04.0   | Kernel 3.2  | r8169 & r8168 not working
Ubuntu 11.10     | Kernel 3.0  | r8169 & r8168 not working
Debian 6.0.7     | Kernel 2.6  | r8169 working fine, r8168 working fine
Ubuntu 10.04.4   | Kernel 2.6  | r8169 working with known problems, r8168 working fine
Smos1.2 (Debian) | Kernel 2.6  | r8169 working with known problems, r8168 working fine
```

Conclusion: The rev 06 of RTL8111/8168 is not working above AMD64 Kernel 2.6

- This nic works with all i386 kernels.
- It didn't work with ndiswrapper on amd64.

Regression:

- I blacklisted the driver r8169 and installed 8.036.00 over dkms based on this post by [praseodym](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/lan-karte-funktioniert-nicht/#post-3005217).
- I also tried the 037.deb package from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/r8168-dkms/8.037.00-1) with no luck
- I tried static ip's / dhcp but the connection isn't working.

I'd like to offer a small BTC Donation like 0.03 BTC for a working solution because I need this fixed asap.

Here's a list of infos and logs:

```
$ uname -a
Linux miner-rig1 3.8.0-34-generic #49~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 13 18:05:00 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2
04:06.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Allied Telesis AT-2500TX/ACPI [1259:2503]
        Kernel driver in use: 8139too
--
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
        Kernel driver in use: r8168

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search fritz.box

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       miner-rig1
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:05:00.0 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="94:de:80:a7:c4:ea", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"    
# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.4/0000:04:06.0 (8139too)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:30:84:2a:cc:12", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:de:80:a7:c4:ea
          inet6 addr: fe80::96de:80ff:fea7:c4ea/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:370 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1522 (1.5 KB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:76 Base address:0xe000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:30:84:2a:cc:12
          inet addr:192.168.188.41  Bcast:192.168.188.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::230:84ff:fe2a:cc12/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36773 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1304413 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:35558704 (35.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:64402 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64402 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:90356022 (90.3 MB)  TX bytes:90356022 (90.3 MB)

$ route -n
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.188.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.188.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1

$ dmesg
[    0.309661] pci 0000:05:00.0: [10ec:8168] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.309676] pci 0000:05:00.0: reg 10: [io  0xb000-0xb0ff]
[    0.309701] pci 0000:05:00.0: reg 18: [mem 0xfe600000-0xfe600fff 64bit]
[    0.309717] pci 0000:05:00.0: reg 20: [mem 0xd0900000-0xd0903fff 64bit pref]
[    0.309784] pci 0000:05:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.309785] pci 0000:05:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    1.273121] r8168 Gigabit Ethernet driver 8.036.00-NAPI loaded
[    1.273203] r8168 0000:05:00.0: irq 76 for MSI/MSI-X
[    1.283778] eth%d: 0xffffc9000007e000, 94:de:80:a7:c4:ea, IRQ 76
[    1.283940] r8168: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
[    1.283944] r8168  Copyright (C) 2013  Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com>
[    1.283944]  This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details, please see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
[    1.283944]  This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
[    8.423951] r8168: eth0: link up

$ cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

$ lsmod
8139too                32183  0
r8168                 260948  0

$ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes

$ cat syslog (eth0 is the corrupt 8111 controller, eth1 is working)
21:16:56 kernel: [    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 28 pages/cpu @ffff88023ec00000 s84928 r8192 d21568 u262144
21:16:56 kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s84928 r8192 d21568 u262144 alloc=1*2097152
21:16:56 kernel: [    0.256453] NET: Registered protocol family 16
21:16:56 kernel: [    0.342139] NetLabel: Initializing
21:16:56 kernel: [    0.342141] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
21:16:56 kernel: [    0.342142] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
21:16:56 kernel: [    0.342150] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
21:16:56 kernel: [    0.357055] NET: Registered protocol family 2
21:16:56 kernel: [    0.357763] NET: Registered protocol family 1
21:16:56 kernel: [    0.897306] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
21:16:56 kernel: [    1.218874] NET: Registered protocol family 10
21:16:56 kernel: [    1.219000] NET: Registered protocol family 17
21:16:56 kernel: [    1.278661] r8168 Gigabit Ethernet driver 8.036.00-NAPI loaded
21:16:56 kernel: [    1.278738] r8168 0000:05:00.0: irq 76 for MSI/MSI-X
21:16:56 kernel: [    1.289300] eth%d: 0xffffc9000007e000, 94:de:80:a7:c4:ea, IRQ 76
21:16:56 kernel: [    1.289452] r8168: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
21:16:56 kernel: [    1.289459] r8168  Copyright (C) 2013  Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com>
21:16:56 kernel: [    1.292382] 8139cp: 8139cp: 10/100 PCI Et ernet driver v1.3 (Mar 22, 2004)
21:16:56 kernel: [    1.293719] 8139too: 8139too Fast Etherne  driver 0.9.28
21:16:56 kernel: [    1.294824] 8139too 0000:04:06.0 eth1: RealTek RTL8139 at 0x000000000001c000, 00:30:84:2a:cc:12, IRQ 20
21:16:56 kernel: [    2.148715] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): et 0: link is not ready
21:16:56 kernel: [    2.148720] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): et 1: link is not ready
21:16:56 kernel: [    2.312197] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
21:16:56 kernel: [    2.483450] type=1400 audit(1388348216.756:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=751 comm="apparmor_parser"
21:16:56 kernel: [    2.483604] type=1400 audit(1388348216.756:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=750 comm="apparmor_parser"
21:16:56 kernel: [    2.483610] type=1400 audit(1388348216.756:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=763 comm="apparmor_parser"
21:16:56 kernel: [    2.645814] NET: Registered protocol family 31
21:16:56 avahi-daemon[922]: Network interface enumeration completed.
21:16:56 kernel: [    2.658659] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
21:16:56 NetworkManager[932]: <info> NetworkManager (version 0.9.4.0) is starting...
21:16:56 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Read config file /etc/Ne workManager/NetworkManager.conf
21:16:56 NetworkManager[932]: <info> VPN: loaded org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp
21:16:56 NetworkManager[932]: <info> DNS: loaded plugin dnsmasq
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: init!
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: update_system_hostname
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPluginIfupdown: management mode: unmanaged
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.4/0000:04:06.0/net/eth1, iface: eth1)
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.4/0000:04:06.0/net/eth1, iface: et 1): no ifupdown configuration found.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:05:00.0/net/eth0, iface: eth0)
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:05:00.0/net/eth0, iface: et 0): no ifupdown configuration found.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: end _init.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2010 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    Ifupdown: get unmanaged devices count: 0
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (15243056) ... get_connections.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: (15243056) ... get_connections (managed=false): return empty list.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    keyfile: parsing 8111 dhcp ...
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    keyfile:     read connection '8111 dhcp'
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    keyfile: parsing working eth card ...
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    keyfile:     read connection 'working eth card'
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]:    Ifupdown: get unmanaged devices count: 0
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> modem-manager is now available
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> WiMAX enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Networking is enabled by state file
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <warn> failed to allocate link cache: (-10) Operation not supported
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): carrier is OFF
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): new Ethernet device (driver: '8139too' ifindex: 3)
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): now managed
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): bringing up device.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): carrier now ON (device state 20)
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): preparing device.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <warn> failed to allocate link cache: (-10) Operation not supported
21:16:57 kernel: [    2.773422] 8139too 0000:04:06.0 eth1: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): carrier is OFF
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): new Ethernet device (driver: 'r8168' ifindex: 2)
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): now managed
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): bringing up device.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): preparing device.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
21:16:57 kernel: [    2.832528] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): et 0: link is not ready
21:16:57 kernel: [    2.832766] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): et 0: link is not ready
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'working eth card'.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) starting connection 'working eth card'
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> dhclient started with pid 1058
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
21:16:57 dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1-ESV-R4
21:16:57 dhclient: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
21:16:57 dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth1/00:30:84:2a:cc:12
21:16:57 dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth1/00:30:84:2a:cc:12
21:16:57 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.188.41 on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info>   address 192.168.188.41
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info>   gateway 192.168.188.1
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.188.1'
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info>   domain name 'fritz.box'
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
21:16:57 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
21:16:57 avahi-daemon[922]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv4 with address 192.168.188.41.
21:16:57 avahi-daemon[922]: New relevant interface eth1.IPv4 for mDNS.
21:16:57 avahi-daemon[922]: Registering new address record for 192.168.188.41 on eth1.IPv4.
21:16:58 NetworkManager[932]: <info> DNS: starting dnsmasq...
21:16:58 NetworkManager[932]: <error> [1388348218.141241] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:393] update(): dnsmasq not available on the bus, can't update servers.
21:16:58 NetworkManager[932]: <error> [1388348218.141259] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:395] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'uk.org.thekelleys.dnsmasq': no such name
21:16:58 NetworkManager[932]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
21:16:58 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
21:16:58 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): device state change: ip-config -> activated (reason 'none') [70 100 0]
21:16:58 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Policy set 'working eth card' (eth1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
21:16:58 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) successful, device activated.
21:16:58 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth1) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
21:16:58 NetworkManager[932]: <warn> dnsmasq appeared on DBus: :1.24
21:16:58 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth1): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
21:16:58 avahi-daemon[922]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth1.IPv6 with address fe80::230:84ff:fe2a:cc12.
21:16:58 avahi-daemon[922]: New relevant interface eth1.IPv6 for mDNS.
21:16:58 avahi-daemon[922]: Registering new address record for fe80::230:84ff:fe2a:cc12 on eth1.*.
21:16:59 kernel: [    4.842503] r8168: eth0: link up
21:17:01 kernel: [    6.852980] r8168: eth0: link up
21:17:01 kernel: [    6.853014] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): carrier now ON (device state 20)
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed') [20 30 40]
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Auto-activating connection '8111 dhcp'.
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection '8111 dhcp'
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> dhclient started with pid 1997
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
21:17:01 dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1-ESV-R4
21:17:01 dhclient: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
21:17:01 NetworkManager[932]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
21:17:01 dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/94:de:80:a7:c4:ea
21:17:01 dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/94:de:80:a7:c4:ea
21:17:01 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
21:17:02 avahi-daemon[922]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::96de:80ff:fea7:c4ea.
21:17:02 avahi-daemon[922]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
21:17:02 avahi-daemon[922]: Registering new address record for fe80::96de:80ff:fea7:c4ea on eth0.*.
21:17:02 NetworkManager[932]: <warn> error monitoring device for netlink events: error processing netlink message: Object busy
21:17:04 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
21:17:11 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
21:17:13 NetworkManager[932]: <warn> error monitoring device for netlink events: error processing netlink message: Object busy
```

Comment: I have a working PCI Lan-Card (eth1) installed over which i can connect to the Internet. But eth0 isn't even connected to the router, i can't ping it. Others also have that problem, check the thread i just posted. They haven't found a solution yet

Comment: There's no space for that stupid old pci lan card and i have multiple rigs with the same motherboard where i need this fixed + others would also like to see a fix

Comment: I'd have to change motherboards because this is an onboard lan controller error. But that's the only affordable board with 6 pci-express slots with no alternatives. So it has to be fixed :/

Comment: @5andr0 Same problem... http://askubuntu.com/questions/398050/ubuntu-freeze-when-connecting-ethernet-cable-network-card-is-realtek-rtl8111-81 .... I tested on i386 kernels also not work

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/398050/ubuntu-freeze-when-connecting-ethernet-cable-network-card-is-realtek-rtl8111-81

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the same Gigabyte 990FXA UD5 motherboard, running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I tried the wireless (and crazy popular) USB Edimax EW-7811Un and it won't work. Downloaded the latest Realtek drivers which should work for Linux kernel up to 3.9 but I'm running 3.11. Tried to compile just the same, but getting gazillions of errors. Decided to connect to basic wired connection (shared from my MacBook Pro) temporarily. Can't even do that (Kernel driver in use: r8169). I am THIS close to tossing Ubuntu and just installing Windows (which I loathe with crimson passion).

Comment: @5andr0 Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Visit the [Realtek > NIC's > 10/100/1000M Gigabit Ethernet > PCI Express > software > Unix (Linux)](http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2) and download the driver source for your kernel version.

Comment: After I install these drivers on my laptop the wired connection also stops working.

Comment: @Siddharth Interesting. What version of the driver did you try? 8.041 is current for RTL8111/8168B. Why would you replace the Ethernet driver if it was working with your hardware?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. Let me clarify. With the default ubuntu 15 the laptop works fine on wired network, but wifi does not work. I get the `lshw -C network` as `UNCLAIMED`. After I install the driver from Realtek the wifi still does not work and even wired stops working. As of now I have installed ubuntu 14 and am using an old usb wifi.

Comment: Well since this question regards failure of the wired interface I suggest you create a new question after reviewing http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and http://askubuntu.com/questions/236119/how-do-i-troubleshoot-problems-with-my-wireless-connection

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for years now and with every update that involves a kernel it will reboot with network disconnected, I have it down pat. Turn off the machine, pull the plug , hold the power button for a second or two and try it again. If that fails delete /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and reboot usually does the trick.

Comment: I can't believe that just yanking the power cable did the trick.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

#### Wiggle the cable and force it to the back

Windows was just fine in connecting to my ethernet and acquiring IP address and internet access. Ubuntu also was connecting just fine at the beginning. After a while when I was booting in Ubuntu I had no network at all even though I still had in Windows.

I decided to see what happens with the blinking leds in the lan port, because when I was prompting `ifconfig eth0` had no IP and no Packet activity.

The solution to the problem (which oddly occurred only in Ubuntu) was to wiggle the cable a little bit and forced it a little to the back.