# How can I fix errors installing D-Link DWA-121 wireless driver tarball?

Tags: wireless, drivers, make

I tried the following instructions as given on D-Link's website to install the necessary drivers:

Supported OS and kernel version : LINUX (kernel 2.6.18 ~ 2.6.37)

```
tar zxvf rtl8192CU_linux_v2.0.1406.20110309.tar.gz
cd rtl8192CU_linux_v2.0.1406.20110309
make
su
make install
reboot
```

But I get errors when I run `make`. How to deal the error?

Comment: Please post the error you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your device is supported in newer releases of the Linux kernel. Ubuntu provides a package with 'backports' of this. This is fairly the same as [the answer of chili555](https://askubuntu.com/a/236625/88802), but without downloading from a 3rd party website (potentially untrusted and unsafe) and without the need to compile.

Just do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic
```

and reboot.

You would have come to this step also when following my guide:

- [My WiFi adapter is not working at all, how to troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-where-to-start-troubleshooting)

Comment: its not working at all and answer from chilli555 worked till restard ;P.....neither this adapter is working neither my build in atheros card....what should I do??

Comment: @dg91 If the answer from chili555 worked until restart, *append* a line with just `rtl8192cu` in `/etc/modules`. In one command: `echo rtl8192cu | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`.

Comment: thx ...you seem to know to work in linux ;) so I must ask: any idea why I cant enable my built in atheros ar9285 wireless card ? :)

Comment: @dg91 That's another question I guess?

Comment: @dg91 you said about the main part about my answer: "its not working at all". In the workaround we've used chili555's answer - consider accepting his answer instead and link to my comment. (click on the time next to the comment to get a link) The specific backport package is Ubuntu-only, possible existing in derivatives like Mint. can't tell.

Comment: I am sry...I am new to linux and these forums...I dont understand what you want? sry

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are not using the built-in rtl8192cu because it doesn't actually connect.

The package you downloaded, written for 2.6.xx kernels, is probably never going to compile correctly in 12.04, using a 3.2.0-x kernel. Also, an error at 'make' suggests you haven't installed the necessary build tools. With a temporary ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1.tar.bz2
tar -jxf compat-wireless-3.6.6-1.tar.bz2
cd compat-wireless-3.6.6-1/
./scripts/driver-select rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
```

Comment: man you are a genius!!..worked like charm thanks a lot!! Do you maybe know how to enable my default build in Atheros AR9285 PCI Express network adapter...I never managed to enable it and that is the reason why I buyed this external adapter...if you dont know nvm. thx a lot again! ;)

Comment: -1 `compat-wireless` is provided as a package. avoid building from source, please. See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/236756/88802)

Comment: it was all working good and then after shutdown I doesnt work anymore...when I do "sudo modprobe rtl8192cu" it enables wireless but I cant connect ???

Comment: Please try recompiling again: cd compat-wireless-3.6.6-1/; make clean; make; sudo make install; sudo modprobe -r rtl8192cu && sudo modprobe rtl8192cu. Does it connect now?

Comment: this guy belove allready solved it ...thx :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't have a compiler for `C` (*the Programming Language*) installed.

First of all run the following command in your terminal to install `build-essential`.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then run all the commands as given in instructions.