# Install netgear WNA1000m on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, networking, server, netgear

I have been looking all day on the internet for a solution to installing the Netgear WNA1000m Wifi USB dongle on my Linux Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.

I found some interesting articles on this forum as well on others and I've been gone through some steps succesfully to identify the USB dongle.

What I did:

```
lsusb
```

and after this:

```
modinfo 8192cu | grep 9041
```

The last command gave me an error which said that the module could not be found.

I hope you guys can help me out on installing this wifi dongle.

I'm actually very new to Ubuntu, but I'm willing to learn a lot of the Linux OS and I hope you guys can tell me why and how you did some steps, even if they might be basic.

Thanks already!

---

You can correct my English if I said something incorrect, because it's not my native language

Comment: Take a look at qkslvrwolf's answer to the question: [trying to install Netgear usb wireless adapter](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1806839&page=4). It's the same dongle, the Netgear WNA1000m.

Comment: What was the result of lsusb?

Answer (score -1):

I found this link to be of great help.

[How to install driver for RTL8188CUS Wireless adaptor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236617/how-to-install-driver-for-rtl8188cus-wireless-adaptor)

It discusses the pitfalls of going about it on your own with third party software and provides you with what worked for my problem which is just a slightly different version then what you printed.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]. Please, instead just posting the link add yourself the detailed instructions and your experience while using the solution. Read [ask] for more information.