# Edmiax Mini Wifi Dongle (RTL8188CUS) not working

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, realtek

unforunatley my Edimax EW-7811Un WIfi Dongle with an integrated Realtek RTL8188CUS chip is not working under my ubuntu 12.04.

After having it connected the first time it worked right away and I was able to connect to my WiFi network. However the connection was unstable and it disconnected every couple of minutes.

So I googled and found this tutorial on how to install the correct drivers:
http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/realtek-rtl8188ce-treiber-installieren/2/ (see the second post).

After having executed all the steps my wifi stick gets not recognized as a network device at all.

I tried this [How to install driver for RTL8188CUS Wireless adaptor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236617/how-to-install-driver-for-rtl8188cus-wireless-adaptor) which unfortunately didn't chnage the situation.

Then I tried to follow this tutorial to figure out what went wrong:
[My WiFi adapter is not working at all, how to troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-where-to-start-troubleshooting)

The device is not shown, when I execute sudo lshw -C network.

Do you have any ideas how to get it to work?