# Wifi does not work with internet

Tags: wireless, networking, configuration, dns

I just cretaed a dual boot Windows/Ubuntu. My Wifi works properly in windows, but it does not let me go on the Internet when in Ubuntu. DHCP seems to work since I apparently received a 192.168.1.3 address that btw **is the only one I can ping**. I can neither ping the router address (that is 192.168.1.1.) I had a look at some config file, and I can see the wlan with iwconfig, but in the /etc/network/interfaces file there is nothing but

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback
```

It seems strange to me (but yes, maybe is because I'm just a developer ) not seeing anything about wlan0.

What can be the problem?

wifi card adater is  D-LINK N 150 Micro USB Adaper DWA 121

Ubuntu version 12.04 LTS

Chip on the pen is RTL8188

**EDIT**
as per @innerand suugestion i downloaded from another computer the backport, but trying to install I've got a dependency not found:

```
[sudo] password for fpollano: 
Selecting previously unselected package linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.2.0-56-generic:i386.
(Reading database ... 140014 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.2.0-56-generic:i386 (from linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.2.0-56-generic_3.2.0-56.45_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.2.0-56-generic:i386:
 linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.2.0-56-generic:i386 depends on linux-image-3.2.0-56-generic.
dpkg: error processing linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.2.0-56-generic:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_GB.utf8
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.2.0-56-generic:i386
fpollano@ubuntu:/tmp$
```

No idea on how to find what is missing

Answer (score 1):

There is a driver problem with this wifi-adapter (Chipset: Realtek RTL8188CUS).

See [How to install driver for RTL8188CUS Wireless adaptor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236617/how-to-install-driver-for-rtl8188cus-wireless-adaptor)

Probably solution:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic
```

Comment: is it possible to install the backport without internet? Which file are needed?

Comment: You can download the package from here [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/devel/linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic) and install it manually (just double click the deb-file on your system).

Comment: I did but it miss some dependencies :(

Comment: Looks like a kernel missmatch. Find out your Kernel-version with 'uname -r' and search for the matching packet (on the right side of the linked page you find _Similar Packages_ for different kernel-versions) -- or find internet over ethernet and use apt-get on your machine ;)

Comment: I'm trying I manage to share my win7 notebook wired connection with ubuntu. PAckages to choose via apt-get anyway are still a mess

Comment: thanks for all your help: unfortunately even loading the package does not fix the problem. So I switched to virtual box Hostes by windows 8: it works better