# How do I enable Bluetooth on my Lenovo IdeaPad Z580?

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth

I have a [Lenovo IdeaPad Z580](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/laptop/ideapad/z-series/z580/) with a built-in Bluetooth adapter running Ubuntu 12.10.

It seems I can't enable it. It works fine in Windows 7, but in Ubuntu the option to enable it in the upper right corner seems not to work. In the settings it says it's off and if I flip the switch to enable it nothing happens. Everything remains grayed out and '**Bluetooth disabled**' message remains there.

I also installed the Blueman applet and it doesn't find any adapters. Any thoughts about getting my Bluetooth enabled?

Below is some more hardware information.

---

Killswitch status:

```
rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Kernel messages:

```
dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    3.559047] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    3.559067] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.559068] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.559070] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.559073] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.570059] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.570062] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.573063] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    3.573068] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    3.573069] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

HCI command-line tools:

```
hcitool dev
Devices:
(yes blank)

hciconfig <comes up blank>
```

USB devices:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b2e1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:2003 Lite-On Technology Corp. 

lsusb -v | grep Blue
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
(this line was repeated several times)
```

Comment: what is output of `rfkill list all` once the Bluetooth is turned ON?

Comment: Hi VRU, it's still:                                                      `rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no`

Comment: Any ideas? this laptop's touchpad is pretty bad and classes are about to start, so this may force me to go back to win7 while at school, which i was hoping to avoid... (i have a BT mouse)

Comment: Surely someone should know?

Comment: Grab a cheap USB mouse, even if you could connect, you might still not have a working mouse (launchpad bug 1098959).  Seems to have some problems with the upowerd deamon.

Comment: @user104588 is it working now?

Answer (score 2):

#### Not supported in Ubuntu's default kernel

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:2003 Lite-On Technology Corp.
```

Is your bluetooth receiver. It's not supported in the stable Ubuntu Linux kernels at the time of writing. A patch to enable support on it has been submitted: [Patchwork Bluetooth: Add support for BCM20702A0 [04ca, 2003]](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/1436161/) in September 2012.

Try a more recent kernel and it should just work. I'm running Linux 3.7.3 and it's supported:

```
modinfo btusb | grep -i 04CA.2003
alias:          usb:v04CAp2003d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

See [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/235280/88802) for wireless LAN issues step 6 (*Try the latest stable Linux kernel*) on how to upgrade your kernel to a more recent one.

#### Why do I see it using `rfkill` then?

Killswitch support is something completely different than support of the device behind this switch. The message about Bluetooth being disabled may be a bit misleading. The application assumes the bluetooth adapter device to appear once it has unlocked the killswitch. In your case, the adapter isn't supported, so that explains why it doesn't show up.

The `dmesg` output always shows traces of Bluetooth as that's just the generic kernel module initializing for general Bluetooth support in the kernel. It has nothing to do with your Bluetooth adapter at that point.

#### Please report this as a bug

Please also open a bug on the Ubuntu bugtracker against the `linux` package to get support for this backported in the Quantal release kernel. Ask to get this commit merged in the stable kernel:

```
commit 0c1abbd1aa0416258881c303a88e618cbca0759c
Author: Jaroslav Resler <resler@cs.cas.cz>
Date:   Tue Sep 11 17:25:32 2012 +0800

    Bluetooth: Add support for BCM20702A0 [04ca, 2003]

    Add another vendor specific ID for BCM20702A0.
```

Currently, it's only being maintained since Linux 3.7.x as far as I can see:

```
$ git branch -a --contains 0c1abbd
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/linux-3.7.y
  remotes/origin/master
```

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

For the Precise kernel this is being requested in the following bug already, as it's been incorporated in the 3.2.36 kernel which is being maintained a lot longer than 3.5 is.

- [LP Bug #1096966: Precise update to 3.2.36 stable release](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1096966)

Comment: even though I am not the OP but your elaborated answer makes sense. 50+