# I can't turn on my bluetooth?

Tags: 12.04, networking, indicator, bluetooth

Ubuntu 12.04.01 - i can't turn on my bluetooth. I am on a dell vostro 1500 with **wireless 355 bluetooth module (bluetooth 2.0 + EDR)**. When i turn the bluetooth on from the indicator and then click on bluetooth settings, it says the bluetooth is disabled. Bluetooth is enabled in BIOS settings. Is there a possible fix for this?

**rfkill list** output is as follows:

0: phy0: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

lsusb output for this device:

```
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
```

uname -r

```
3.2.0-37-generic
```

I have tried:

```
sudo su
modprobe btusb
lsmod | grep btusb
```

to confirm module is loaded, then

```
sh -c "echo 0x0a5c 0x4500 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id"
```

Nothing happens at all.

```
hcitool dev
```

returns no devices.

Comment: What's the output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: Check your BIOS settings to see if it is enabled there.

Comment: Yes. It is enabled in BIOS settings.

Comment: **0: phy0: Wireless LAN**
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
**1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN**
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
**2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth**
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: What bluetooth adapter do you have? I mean the numerical information, not the vendor retail name. Include the output of `lsusb`. You may have a similar case as [How do I enable Bluetooth on my Lenovo IdeaPad Z580?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/239827/how-do-i-enable-bluetooth-on-my-lenovo-ideapad-z580/245349#245349)

Comment: Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)

Comment: @user1930341 Can you try running `sudo sh -c "echo 0x0a5c 0x4500 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id"`? This device seems really new, and not well supported at the moment, but as reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-bluetooth/wiki/USB), it's just another device ID and does not require any change to the driver.