# How to enable bluetooth using Lenovo 480G

Tags: 12.10, bluetooth, lenovo

This has been mentioned before for different Lenovo models (here: [How do I enable Bluetooth on my Lenovo IdeaPad Z580?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239827/how-do-i-enable-bluetooth-on-my-lenovo-ideapad-z580)).

The toggle switch shows off, switching it on does nothing,  different BT dameons do not work either.  There was a suggestion to upgrade the kernel to 3.7* (I am running 3.6* now), but when I did this, I could not figure out how to get wired network driver support.  My mistake for getting a Lenovo, looks good, but the linux support seems to be lacking.

```
rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Any suggestions how to get the bluetooth enabled?

```
kernel messages:
dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   26.701536] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   26.701554] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   26.701556] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   26.701557] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   26.701560] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   26.719851] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   26.719855] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   26.719856] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   26.800299] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   26.800301] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:0294 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04b4:0033 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. Mouse
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04d9:1503 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Shortboard Lefty
```

Comment: Start by adding the commands and results from that topic you quoted. (`lsusb` seems to be the one that is needed (post it in the question please) (check the vendor string).

Comment: tks, the post I quoted gave the solution as upgrading to 3.7. seems the BT adapter in my NB is not supported until kernel 3.7, but my wired network adapter doesnt seem to have support when I install in that kernel.  I am wondering if there is another way around it.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Lenovo ThinkPad X200 Tablet and Bluetooth is working for me. Maybe this will help you.

I use `bluez` (4.101-r5) and have the daemon start at the default runlevel by OpenRC. For connecting to devices, I use the applet from `gnome-bluetooth` (3.6.1). Once you get that installed, it should add a "Bluetooth Settings" section to your Gnome Control Centre.

Here's some additional info.

**`rfkill`**:

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

**`lsusb`**:

```
$ lsusb | grep -i bluetooth
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 0a5c:2145 Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth with Enhanced Data Rate II
```

**`lsmod`**:

```
bluetooth             150763  25 bnep,hidp,btusb,rfcomm
rfkill                 13496  6 cfg80211,thinkpad_acpi,bluetooth
```

**`dmesg`**:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    5.352964] usb 4-2: Product: ThinkPad Bluetooth with Enhanced Data Rate II
[    5.383455] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    5.383470] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.383477] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.383480] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.383483] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.216268] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.216272] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.216287] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.297778] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    9.297794] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    9.297798] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   25.493122] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   25.493134] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[  617.705170] usb 4-2: Product: ThinkPad Bluetooth with Enhanced Data Rate II
[ 4486.165016] usb 4-2: Product: ThinkPad Bluetooth with Enhanced Data Rate II
```

**kernel config**:

```
$ zcat /proc/config.gz | grep 'CONFIG_BT[=_]'
CONFIG_BT=m
CONFIG_BT_RFCOMM=m
CONFIG_BT_RFCOMM_TTY=y
CONFIG_BT_BNEP=m
CONFIG_BT_BNEP_MC_FILTER=y
CONFIG_BT_BNEP_PROTO_FILTER=y
CONFIG_BT_HIDP=m
CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB=m
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBTSDIO is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIUART is not set
CONFIG_BT_HCIBCM203X=m
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBPA10X is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBFUSB is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIDTL1 is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBT3C is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBLUECARD is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUART is not set
# CONFIG_BT_HCIVHCI is not set
# CONFIG_BT_MRVL is not set
# CONFIG_BT_ATH3K is not set
```

Comment: tks for the answer, I have all of the above installed.the gnome BT shows in the tray, but no adapters.  I also have blueman 1.23 installed and running in the tray, when clik adapters, returns 'no adapters found'. lsusb | grep -i bluetooth command in terminal returns nothing

Comment: @RobertVirgin could you please paste the output of `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep 'CONFIG_BT[=_]'`? Also, this might sound dumb, but do you have a hardware switch for networking (or just bluetooth), is it on/off? Is the Bluetooth LED (if you have one) lit?

Comment: @RobertVirgin to me `lsusb | grep -i bluetooth` shows nothing when I have the network switch off on the side of the laptop. When I turn the switch back on, then the bluetooth adapter appears. It is a hardware switch.

Comment: output: gzip: /proc/config.gz: No such file or directory. there is no networking switch. I am trying to find the BT adapter chip maker, then maybe can find correct driver support. so far it does not seem to have support in the kernel versions I run now

Comment: @RobertVirgin that's odd, even if you have no support, `lsusb` should show the device string, if your bluetooth adapter is hooked up to a USB port (as in most laptops).