# wifi driver for HP Pavillion

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have installed UBUNTU 12.04 or on my HP Pavillion. Ubuntu works fine, but wifi driver is nor working^ attempt to switch wifi on causes almost immediate failure and led indicator is showing  that WIFI is off.
This is not hardware problem, since for WINDOWS 7 (I have alternative HDD with windows 7) wireless network works fine and I can surf through internet

Where can I get correct wifi driver and how to update my current driver (or porbably update UBUNTU to newer version?)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the output of lspci -v ?

Comment: In a terminal, type "lspci" and look for anything that has to do with Wireless, I know there is another command that tells you your Card name, so look for the lscpi commands and then google drivers for your card. If it's Broadcom, good luck because it is very difficult.

Comment: Please provide the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|wireless)"` run from a terminal. While you're at it, also run `rfkill list`. Do this by copy&pasting the exact output **into** your question by **editing** it. This is because we need more hardware information and to diagnose whether it is your wireless killswitch or just a driver issue.

Comment: Please also have a look at [My WiFi adapter is not working at all. Where to start troubleshooting?](http://askubuntu.com/q/235279/88802)

Answer (score 0):

You could look in System Settings then Software Sources and in that there should be a tab for Additional Drivers. That's where I found the Broadcom driver for my Dell Studio