# Wifi Not working with 13.04

Tags: wireless, connection

I have a DVD with Ubuntu on it, but as a test I wanted to see the product and it won't connect with my laptop's wifi.  Do I need to configure something for it to work?  My Gateway laptop however, connects with Vista to the Internet.

Comment: Please have a loot at [My WiFi adapter is not working at all. Where to start troubleshooting?](http://askubuntu.com/q/235279/88802)

Comment: sudo lspci -nn will list PCI devices, including WiFi and other expansion cardseven though the kernel mayn't have a driver for them. sudo lshw -class network also shows what's recognized; please post the results of both here along with sudo lspci .

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the modem you could try connecting using the LAN cable into one of the LAN terminals available in the modem. And if that works, then you can look for the wifi driver online.