# Wireless doesn't work!

Tags: wireless, networking, dell

I've installed Ubuntu on my dell vostro and it can't find my wireless network. It doesn't even try! It comes up with a message telling me there are additional drivers available for my wireless device but when I try to install them it tells me this can't be done! Any clues here?

Comment: Please have a look at [My WiFi adapter is not working at all. Where to start troubleshooting?](http://askubuntu.com/q/235279/88802) for basic troubleshooting of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your terminal
$ sudo rm /dev/rfkill  and see if that gives you a connection so you can download the additional drivers.

Answer (score 0):

**This is where to look:** [My WiFi adapter is not working at all, how to troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-where-to-start-troubleshooting). It provides answers to the common problems. If not, see below.

Take a look at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide. It provides directions for troubleshooting WiFi.

To find what your specific device is, go to the first link and click "devices" near the top of the article. Follow the instructions on that page.

To install the correct drivers, look here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide/Drivers

It may be a bit complicated, but going through the process carefully should fix you problem. Not to discourage you, but I have had problems with Broadcom drivers in the past. Yours might be one (I can't tell with the information you provided).