# Broadcom 4311 driver issues

Tags: drivers

-Hi, i am looking for help with installing the correct drivers for a broadcom 4311 NIC. I am using Ubuntu 13.04 on a dell vostro 1500 and this has been terribly frustrating. I have installed Ubuntu on three other dell's, two of which i had to import drivers via SD, all with Broadcom NICs. I Have never been so stumped.

-The major issue for me is trying to install driver/firmware with no eth or wifi to the laptop in question. I have tried to install the STA proprietary driver = no luck, tried the    bcmwl driver = no luck' also tried installing b43-fwcutter/firmware-b43-installer and these won't install due to error during installation requires version (>= 015-14.1). Downloaded the required version and still get error message. I have followed several different posts that have variations of installing the drivers. Overall its becoming very irritating with all the different forums on this subject and i would like to hear what some of the people from the community think. Please Help!

Comment: take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers (possible duplicate)

Comment: also see this help.ubuntu.com article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: wl - Proprietary Broadcom STA Wireless driver 

For Chip ID {{{BCM4311}}}, BCM4312, BCM4313, BCM4321, BCM4322, BCM43224, BCM43225, BCM43227 and BCM43228.

Install either bcmwl-kernel-source (instructions below) OR the broadcom-sta (instructions at http://wiki.debian.org/wl) packages.

b43 - Open source driver

For Chip ID BCM4306 (rev 03), BCM4309, {{{BCM4311}}}, BCM4312, BCM4318, BCM4322, BCM4331, BCM43224 and BCM43225. WHICH ONE!

Comment: Which post is most specific to my situation because i can not apt-get from my LAN....http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers wasnt much help, where do you think all the frustrating posts i was reading came from.

Comment: You can try following the instructions in all of the answers to the above question. If it says 'or', then take your pick!

Comment: [SOLVED]  I believe the package you need is linux-firmware-nonfree. http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/all/linux-firmware-nonfree/download

Please download the package, transfer it on a USB stick or similar to the desktop of the Xubuntu machine. Open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and do:

sudo dpkg -i Desktop/linux*.deb
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
You should be all set.

Comment: I was having trouble finding the right firmware for sure. thank you all, i was about to lose it for a min. I had been at it for about a week...

Answer (score 1):

You can easily install the firmware without an internet connection. Please download this file to a USB key or similar: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/b43.zip  Drag and drop the file to the desktop of your Ubuntu machine. Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now open a terminal and do:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
sudo cp Desktop/b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43
```

Now we unload and reload the driver so it sees and uses the firmware:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

Your wireless should now be working.