# difficulties with bcm4313 driver in ubuntu studio 13.04

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I have recently installed ubuntu studio 13.04 on my netbook. It is excellent, but i have some problems with my WiFi.

If I use the command `lspci` I can see that I have a **Broadcom bcm4313** wireless card installed. If I run the command `iwconfig` there is no wlan0!

It seems that Ubuntu does not pick up the WiFi card or the card is blacklisted.

Comment: Please do some basic troubleshooting first. And *edit* your question to include more specific hardware information. [My WiFi adapter is not working at all. Where to start troubleshooting?](http://askubuntu.com/q/235279/88802)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 13.04, I believe the default bcmwl-kernel-source will not work correctly for your Broadcom 4313. I recommend that you get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Or, if yours is a 32-bit system:

```
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

Confirm 32- or 64-bit:

```
arch
```

Then do:

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Reboot and give us your report.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you can install the driver going to "Software & updates" (search in the dash) and then to the "Additional drivers" tab. Otherwise, you can to manually install the Proprietary Broadcom STA Wireless driver (assuming you have wired internet connection) with:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source`
stop any other driver working:
`sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma` and load the driver with: `sudo modprobe wl`

Reference:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.