# Internet extremelly slow UBUNTU 13.04 Alfa Awus036h

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, ping

I have a peculiar problem. Presently I have Win7, Backtrack 5r3, and freshly installed Ubuntu 13.04.

I have Alfa Awus036h as my 2nd usb Wifi card. Both backtrack and this new Ubuntu recognize it straightaway and use appropriate driver. When I connect to the INTERNET the connection is slow and sometimes no connectivity at all, but it doesn't drop IP address or anything, connected at all times. When I am  in windows the the card is flying, never any issue, going fast. But in Backtrack & Ubuntu it's incredibly slow. When I try to ping any website, or even my defaul gateway I get like 70-80 percent packet loss. Basically when I browse the net it's way slower than 3g snail. What's strange is when I use the card in Backtrack for Pen-testing it works like a charm! So I know know.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Anyone? Please?

Comment: See the section "Identifying the exact hardware" in my Q&A here on how to do acquire exact hardware details. Include that in your question so we can help you better. http://askubuntu.com/a/235280/88802

Answer (score -1):

Use: `sudo iwconfig wlan1 rate 5.5M auto`

and it will work.