# Drivers for TP-LINK TL-WN725N Nano USB Wireless N adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers

Can you advise me on what drivers to install for the `TP-LINK TL-WN725N` USB wireless adapter on UBUNTU 12.04.  `TP-LINK` only provide `Windows drivers`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Low wifi signal in 14.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661446/low-wifi-signal-in-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 11):

Even I had same problem and fixed it. Try the code below one by one in terminal having the adapter connected. You can see changes in terminal after each code.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
cd rtl8188eu
make all
sudo make install
sudo insmod 8188eu.ko
```

After this restart your system. You can find the network list. Hope this helps.

(More instructions in the [package git](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu).)

Comment: Seems to work well so far.  It wasn't necessary to reboot.  Thanks!  Though actually I didn't think to check if the adapter works without installing this driver.

Comment: Also work on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

1. Have a look at [My WiFi adapter is not working at all. Where to start troubleshooting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-where-to-start-troubleshooting)
2. Try: `sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-precise-generic` (You find more information to this at 1.)