# Wifi driver problems in trusty tahir, back to windows?

Tags: wireless, usb

I've had loads of problems getting Wifi working properly on my HP laptop. the on-board chip is a pig.

I got a TP link TL-WN725N Wifi dongle as the eBay seller assured me there were Linux drivers on the disk. There aren't of course.

I've worked through Naveen's list of commands [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/381574/drivers-for-tp-link-tl-wn725n-nano-usb-wireless-n-adapter/570960#570960) but don't really know what they mean. All appeared ok until the last line when I got

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module 8188eu.ko: Device or resource busy
```

Since this the HP wireless chip works even worse than before, cutting off and on for no reason. The TP link only has 1/5 signal strength when I'm one meter from the router.

Help, my wife already switches back to windows 8 whenever she's on the laptop

I've tried everything I can find on this and other forums, I don’t want to go back to windows but I need Wifi.

I think this is about the Wifi chip on the HP laptop:

```
RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
logical name: wlan0
version: 01
serial: 34:23:87:27:ca:11
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
```

I believe this is the dongle description:

```
Wireless interface physical id: 2
bus info: usb@3:1
logical name: wlan2
serial: e8:de:27:a1:13:ef
capabilities: Ethernet
physical wireless configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=192.168.0.12 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot and follow the instructions there to determine what the problem is. Add the outputs of the commands in this answer to your original question above. This will help the experts understand which WiFi chip your HP laptop has and the right course of action.

Answer (score 0):

```
 apt-get update

 apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

 apt-get update

 apt-get install build-essential

 apt-get install git

 git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu

 cd rtl8188eu

 make all

 make install

 insmod 8188eu.ko

 ifconfig #(check to see if your wireless wlan cards is now listed)
```

should get you going.

Since it giving you device busy, try this

```
 lsmod | grep 8188
```

if the result looks like “r8188eu 7990995 0″

```
 sudo modprobe -r r8188eu
```

then, you can (from the rtl8188eu directory)

```
 sudo insmod 8188eu.ko
```

Edit: This device works with Raspbian (Debian based) with no install needed, so I think there may already be a driver setup, but it may be outdated or just need to be removed and installed again using the git version.

Comment: I think this is about the wifi chip on the hp laptop    RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 34:23:87:27:ca:11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz

Comment: I believe this is the dongle       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:1
       logical name: wlan2
       serial: e8:de:27:a1:13:ef
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=192.168.0.12 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn

Comment: geoff, should i run the device busy commands before the update commands?

Comment: Yes. Do the remove and then go back to rtl8188eu directory. Notice right now your using what came with ubuntu (driver=r8188eu). The github driver output once installed should be different

Comment: ok, i did all that, all went well except the last entry  insmod: ERROR: could not insert module 8188eu.ko: File exists!

Comment: it also still says driver=rtl8188ee    i went to close the terminal to reboot but it says theres a process still running, i dont know what this process is. should i kill and reboot or have i done a wrongy somewhere?

Comment: ok, i rebooted, as far as i can see there is no difference. same driver same connection problems including messing up tablets connection. I dont know why it would do this but when i'm in w8 the tablet connects fine, in ubuntu it doesnt.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of further help. I was going to try to replicate the issue, but as it turns out i have a driver=rtl8192cu. I plug it in and it just works. I am however also on an HP laptop so I was going to try to help you there, but mine is a product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros, and again, both work just fine in Ubuntu 14.10. Again, sorry I could not help.