# Installed Ubuntu and can't connect to WIFI

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu and can't connect to the WIFI. The Wired connection is working and everything else is fine.

Comment: It would help if we knew what type of wifi card you have. Run `sudo lshw -C network` in a terminal and edit your question with what it says for "vendor: ..." under any wireless interface that appears. Also see  See http://askubuntu.com/a/235280/15939

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to connect to the wifi:
Go to System Settings, and go to the Network tab. Select "Wireless Connection" from the left panel. Then, from the drop-down, select the network you want to connect to. It should prompt for a password (if there is one). Enter the password, and it should pop up a little notification saying something like "connected to network 54mbps" or something like that. If you don't get the notification, then there must be a problem either with your wifi card in your computer, or with your router. I would recommend restarting your router, and trying to connect again. If that doesn't work, then restart your computer. If none of that works, then it gets very complicated from there.

Hope this helps!
--Michael