# No wireless connections show up.

Tags: wireless

I had a really slow computer (acer aspire one) with windows 7,  so i decided to install ubuntu to make it faster. Everything went smooth but now when i'm in it i have a problem, it doesn't show any wireless connections and the light on my wireless adapter doesn't shine. I tried restarting and also checking several times if my adapter is on. Are there any solutions for this? Really need help please.

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the drivers Ubuntu's using if it's only giving you this issue in the Ubuntu installation. If the laptop has an ethernet port and you have a cable, try hooking that up temporarily and typing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` into a terminal and see if any package updates come up. These might hold a solution.

Comment: i usb teethered the connection from my phone all the updates and upgrades have finished i rebooted the computer but still nothing happened :( still not showing any connections at all