# Upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 no wireless

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, upgrade, internet

I just upgraded and lost the wireless connection. Here some basic information which might be helpful:

- Dell Inspiron i3-3217U Dual-Core CPU @ 1.8GHz 64-bit
- Chip ID: BCM43143
- PCI-ID: 14e4:4365
- Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

Below the result of the `sudo lshw -C network` command:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 34:17:eb:54:39:dd
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:c0500000-c0507fff
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 34:17:eb:54:39:dd
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:c0500000-c0507fff
```

and the `rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself. Also, don't add such information into answers to your question, because it only adds headache to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `Software and updates`
- Make sure that in `Additional drivers` tab WiFi driver is set to Broadcom driver.

If that does not work please post the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `sudo rfkill list` for further debugging.

Comment: configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits

Comment: clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:c0500000-c0507fff
amy@amy-Inspiron-3521:~$
amy@amy-Inspiron-3521:~$ sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
amy@amy-Inspiron-3521:~$

Comment: Might be your driver is not loaded properly.Can you try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/608068/369873)