# wifi list won't show and even ethernet won't show

Tags: wireless, drivers, ethernet

my wifi list and ethernet doesn't show up. I've had this problem for days now. what do I do? there is no additional drivers.
even the wifi icon isn't showing.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/235280/295286

Comment: It would be especially useful for others if you included output of the diagnostic script http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/295286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that NetworkManager is properly installed and not messed up. To find try the following command in terminal:
which NetworkManager

It should return /usr/sbin/NetworkManager

To reinstall NetworkManager have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager