# Trying to connect to the internet, no WiFi symbol in the top right

Tags: wireless, internet

Title says it all. I'm trying to connect to my WiFi network, but the WiFi icon that's supposed to be in the top right corner is no where to be seen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My WiFi adapter is not working at all, how to troubleshoot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; nmcli -f all device show | sed '/^GENERAL.DEVICE:[ ]\+lo$/,/^$/d; /^AP\[[0-9]\+\]\./d'` The first command will produce a list of pci devices that include net and the second command will show some info on how the Network Manager sees them

Comment: How can we give you a good answer when you don't want to provide basic info about your wifi?

Answer (score 1):

There should be Network or internet connection option in top panel (generally right side). Also Check if the wifi is enabled or not in settings or using a wifi enabling switch (generally on laptop). Also you can try to connect your pc to a wired connection and download latest updates and also if a proprietary driver is available (check from settings in software sources under additional drivers) try that.

Comment: There is a network setting in the settings but when i click on it it says the system settings are not compatible with these settings or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Use a USB external WiFi adapter until the problem is solved. It should definitely connect. If it does, lets get started.

Most probably, the issue is with firmware. Try installing ath10k firmware using the following commands(exactly) in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/sumdog/ath10k-firmware.git
cd ath10k-firmware/ath10k
sudo cp -r QCA6174/  /lib/firmware/ath10k
sudo chmod +x /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/*
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci  &&  sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
sudo -i
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
exit
```

Remove the USB external WiFi Adapter and reboot your system. Now, check for the wireless connection. If it doesn't show any improvement,  let's install a newer kernel version:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-headers-4.4.8-040408-generic_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-headers-4.4.8-040408_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/linux-image-4.4.8-040408-generic_4.4.8-040408.201604200335_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
sudo -i
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
exit
```

Reboot. If the correct firmware is installed, the wireless should now be working.

Comment: We don't know what wireless adapter or version of Ubuntu that Bobot_10 is running. Without knowing either of those, it seems (to me) oddly specific to suggest installing  ath10k firmware and a kernel for Ubuntu Wily, when they might have, say, a Broadcom wireless card on a computer running Xenial.

Comment: @NickWeinberg I understand your concern but since there is no information provided and taking into account my inability to comment on the question, I provided an answer based on the most recently arose issues.