# Wifi Adapter Intel 3160 not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, intel-wireless

After booting up my laptop my wifi suddenly stopped working. At first the lshw could not detect my wifi at all. But then I followed some steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot). I updated all the software after that using the apt-get command. My laptop has Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 Plus Bluetooth*. I installed the

```
linux-firmware and linux-firmware-nonfree.
```

The wifi appeared for a while but then disappeared again. I also installed

```
linux-image-generic-lts-quantal.
```

As a result I am unable to run the wifi on windows( dual boot).

here are some command snapshots:

```
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ dmesg | grep wifi
[    6.541370] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 64 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.582068] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.760065] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless     AC 3160, REV=0x164
[    6.760130] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.812690] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.896561] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 805 at /build/linux-aA_g14/linux-                    
3.13.0/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:1010
iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0xcb/0xe0 [iwlwifi]()
[    6.896581] Modules linked in: iwlmvm(+) intel_rapl             x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp mac80211 coretemp kvm_intel kvm iwlwifi snd_hda_intel(+) uvcvideo snd_hda_codec videobuf2_vmalloc crct10dif_pclmul i915(+) crc32_pclmul aesni_intel videobuf2_memops snd_hwdep videobuf2_core rts5139(C) aes_x86_64 videodev lrw snd_pcm gf128mul glue_helper snd_page_alloc rfcomm bnep cfg80211 bluetooth dell_wmi sparse_keymap hid_multitouch ablk_helper cryptd dell_laptop snd_seq_midi dcdbas snd_seq_midi_event mei_me snd_rawmidi snd_seq drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device drm mei snd_timer joydev snd i2c_algo_bit soundcore shpchp serio_raw lpc_ich wmi hid_rmi i2c_hid parport_pc ppdev     i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core lp mac_hid video nls_iso8859_1     parport hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse ahci r8169 libahci mii
[    6.896599]  [<ffffffffa055979a>] ? iwl_read32+0x1a/0x90 [iwlwifi]
[    6.896601]  [<ffffffffa055acbb>] iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0xcb/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[    6.896604]  [<ffffffffa054d7f1>] iwl_set_bits_mask_prph+0x31/0x140     [iwlwifi]
[    6.896607]  [<ffffffffa055c83f>] iwl_trans_pcie_start_fw+0x11f/0x9c0 [iwlwifi]
[    6.896616]  [<ffffffffa054f63a>] ? iwl_init_notification_wait+0x6a/0xa0 [iwlwifi]
[    6.896625]  [<ffffffffa055b1be>] ? iwl_trans_pcie_start_hw+0xde/0x1f0 [iwlwifi]
[    6.896631]  [<ffffffffa054dc8a>] _iwl_op_mode_start.isra.2+0x4a/0xb0     [iwlwifi]
[    6.896633]  [<ffffffffa054ddb1>] iwl_opmode_register+0xc1/0xf0         [iwlwifi]
[    7.872285] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Hardware error detected.  Restarting.
[    7.872286] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CSR values:
[    7.872287] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: (2nd byte of CSR_INT_COALESCING is CSR_INT_PERIODIC_REG)
[    7.872291] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_HW_IF_CONFIG_REG: 0X00c89204
[    7.872303] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:          CSR_INT_COALESCING: 0X80000040
[    7.872307] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                     CSR_INT: 0X20000000
[    7.872310] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                CSR_INT_MASK: 0X00000000
[    7.872313] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_FH_INT_STATUS: 0X00000000
[    7.872318] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_GPIO_IN: 0X00000000
[    7.872321] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                   CSR_RESET: 0X00000003
[    7.872324] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                CSR_GP_CNTRL: 0X080003dc
[    7.872327] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                  CSR_HW_REV: 0X00000164
[    7.872332] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:              CSR_EEPROM_REG: 0X00000000
[    7.872335] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:               CSR_EEPROM_GP: 0X80000000
[    7.872338] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:              CSR_OTP_GP_REG: 0X803a0000
[    7.872341] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_GIO_REG:     0X00080042
[    7.872346] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:            CSR_GP_UCODE_REG: 0X00000000
[    7.872349] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_GP_DRIVER_REG: 0X00000000
[    7.872352] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP1: 0X00000000
[    7.872355] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP2: 0X00000000
[    7.872359] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 CSR_LED_REG: 0X00000018
[    7.872362] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_DRAM_INT_TBL_REG: 0X00000000
[        7.872366] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_GIO_CHICKEN_BITS: 0X27800200
[    7.872369] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:             CSR_ANA_PLL_CFG: 0Xd55555d5
[    7.872373] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:           CSR_HW_REV_WA_REG: 0X0001001a
[    7.872376] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        CSR_DBG_HPET_MEM_REG: 0Xffff0510
[    7.872377] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH register values:
[    7.935410] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:         FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_STTS_WPTR_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[    7.998539] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:        FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_RBDCB_BASE_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[    8.061374] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                  FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_WPTR: 0X5a5a5a5a
[    8.124194] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:         FH_MEM_RCSR_CHNL0_CONFIG_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[    8.187029] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:          FH_MEM_RSSR_SHARED_CTRL_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[    8.249757] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:            FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_STATUS_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[    8.281204] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:    FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_ENABLE_ERR_IRQ2DRV: 0X5a5a5a5a
[    8.312525] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                FH_TSSR_TX_STATUS_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[    8.343988] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0:                 FH_TSSR_TX_ERROR_REG: 0X5a5a5a5a
[    8.343992] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[   13.219463] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to load firmware chunk!
[   13.219469] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
[   13.219473] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[   13.219519] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

```
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: ec:f4:bb:99:ff:fd
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.0.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:60 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b0b00000-b0b00fff memory:b0800000-b0803fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:64 memory:b0a00000-b0a01fff
```

```
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265]
```

```
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ uname -a
Linux ervd-Inspiron-5447 3.13.0-95-generic #142-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 12 17:00:09 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-95-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation 
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     F935FAF50D9A6B3215203C9

alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C02Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C26Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000CC60bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000CC70bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C760bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C770bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C06Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000402Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005770bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A70bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000486Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004870bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004C70bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004C60bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000893sv*sd00000262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000895sv*sd00000222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00005260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004860bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000888sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000891sv*sd00004222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005207bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00004820bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C228bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001318bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001328bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001308bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001118bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001128bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001108bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Bsv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001114bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001014bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001104bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001004bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001124bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001024bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001314bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001214bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001324bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001224bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001204bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-95-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        51:D5:D7:73:F1:07:BA:1B:C0:9D:33:68:38:C4:3C:DE:74:9E:4E:05
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
```

```
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ ls /lib/firmware/ | grep 3160
iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-14.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
iwlwifi-3160-ucode-25.30.14.0
```

Could someone help me with the solution as the wifi is not working accross windows as well( dual boot). I hope i have provided all the information there should be. I am also unable to find the reason for the reason for the problem. After booting up the wifi was suddenly not working.

after trying out the steps mentioned by pilot6 the wifi is still not working

```
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ rfkill list all
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for ervd: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: ec:f4:bb:99:ff:fd
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.0.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b0a00000-b0a00fff memory:b0800000-b0803fff
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ 
ervd@ervd-Inspiron-5447:~$ uname -r
4.4.0-36-generic
```

Comment: @Pilot6  why did you delete your answer? Did anything go wrong?

Comment: My solution did not work.

Comment: I see now the problem. Please post output of `dkms status`

Comment: @Pilot6 it shows no output

Comment: No more ideas, sry.

Comment: What do you think might be causing the problem?

Comment: I would have written an answer if I knew ;-)

Comment: Hey It seems to work now. I guess your solution worked. When I rebooted into windows, the wifi  was working there. Then i rebooted into ubuntu again and now it seems  to work fine. The rfkill shows the wireless interface, lshw as well shows the proper configuration. Thanks

Comment: Sounds good. I will undelete the answer

Comment: If you want you could answer again and i will mark it as sovled @Pilot6

Answer (score 0):

You installed an obsolete kernel.

Both `linux-firmware-nonfree` and `linux-image-generic-lts-quantal` are obsolete.

Run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

and reboot.

Comment: this is not working. The wifi is now not showing even while running the lshw command or rfkill

Comment: Were you connected to internet? Did the kernel install? What does `uname -a` show. Please add output of `dmesg | grep iwl` to your question.

Comment: I am connected to the internet using the ethernet but now there is also a option of Auto Ethernet which I am not sure what it is for. Also the rfkill shows a new message now.

Comment: hey the problem has again crept up after i left the system suspended. I think something is still messing up the system drivers. It is not working on both windows and linux now.

Comment: Hey @Pilot6 the problem has again crept up after I suspended my laptop for a while. I guess i have not been able to reach a permanent solution.

Comment: the bluetooth has also disappeared now and there is no trace of the wireless card except the rfkill which show s the dell-rbtn0

Comment: This is something specific to the laptop UEFI firmware. I suggest to file a bug report.