# How do I get my Realtek wireless USB adapter working? (0bda:0811)

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I've tried following along with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html), and tried searching for the correct driver, but I had trouble figuring out which it was. I did not find clear information pertaining to my specific hardware.

The adapter does not show up with `sudo lshw -C network`.

And lsusb gives:

```
$ lsusb | grep -i realtek
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

I'm running 16.04, dual booting with Windows 10, and this hardware is working in Windows.

Thanks in advance for any help.