# wifi adapter not working after fresh instalation

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth

Hello there just installed Ubuntu and I realized the wifi adapter is not found, however after installing driver it is found now but I cant use it or turn it on. What should I do to make it work ??

```
iwconfig output:

wlp7s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
enp8s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Note:
I have tried to do this : [How to make my pci wifi card rtl8822 working on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926364/how-to-make-my-pci-wifi-card-rtl8822-working-on-ubuntu)
and this one: [Bluetooth and WiFi not working on Ubuntu 14.04 - RTL8822BE PCIe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082335/bluetooth-and-wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-rtl8822be-pcie)
but nothing worked

Comment: We don't know your OS or release details for starters.

Comment: Please edit your post to include what machine and what version of Ubuntu you are running, then we will investigate further.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I have lenovo legion y7000 laptop

Comment: Try running this `lspci | grep Network` in a terminal and edit your post to include the results.

Comment: My wifi adapter is rtl8822be

Comment: Please edit to include results for `rfkill list`