# How to get WNA3100 Netgear Wireless Adapter drivers working without internet

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet

I just installed ubuntu from being previously on windows 10 and I can't connect to the internet. I have a WNA3100 Wireless Netgear adapter that contains drivers which are all .exe, I have no other machines that are currently running linux and ethernet is not an option. I have spent around 2 hours looking at other users questions but they all seem to require another linux machine, I would really appreciate any help whatsoever, thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot

to me the chipset used by netgear whatever is more important; as well as the version of ubuntu you are using (so I know kernel etc) are more important than brand/model. 

the `.exe` is just a wrapper (like `.cab`, `.tar.gz` or `.zip`) which includes installer code & the real kernel.module (driver in windoze talk) that needs adding to your ubuntu kernel to make it work...

Comment: Sorry for the late response I was reading that guide. I am using the latest version of ubuntu, 16.04.2 LTS and my hardware details are... BUS 001 Device 008: 10 08 46 : 90020 Netgear, Inc. WNA3100(v1) Wireless-N 300 [ Broadcom BCM 43231]

Comment: maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers but I note it does mention it noted issues with BCM43231 specifically (its old; but it still applies to 16.04 I noted)

Comment: Does this machine have an internal wifi card or did you have to use the WNA3100 in windows also?  You may want to see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020&highlight=WNA3100)

Comment: My answer is that you probably *can't* get it working with or without internet.

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to go out and purchase a Linux supported pcie adapter, really love Ubuntu so far too :)!

If anyone in the future has this issue and is running Ubuntu I recommend purchasing [this](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833320074) as it didn't require any drivers, worked out of the box.