# Problem with D-Link DWA-182 Wireless AC1200 Dual Band USB Adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

At the beginning I would like to emphasize that I've been struggling with this problem for a long time now and all the solutions that I've found so far have failed. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot/235280#235280) answer, and then I downloaded the drivers from the D-Link website (I will put it in the comment since I cannot post more than two links) and after that I ran those commands (in the folder with the files)

```
chmod +x install.sh
sudo ./install.sh
```

which were followed by the long list of errors

```
   /home/szymon/Desktop/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/core/rtw_debug.c:66:64: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "build time: %s %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
                                                                ^
/home/szymon/Desktop/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  DBG_871X_SEL_NL(sel, "build time: %s %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);
 ^
/home/szymon/Desktop/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
/home/szymon/Desktop/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
/home/szymon/Desktop/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
/home/szymon/Desktop/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/core/rtw_debug.c:66:1: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/home/szymon/Desktop/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/core/rtw_debug.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/szymon/Desktop/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/core/rtw_debug.o] Error 1
Makefile:1395: recipe for target '_module_/home/szymon/Desktop/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/szymon/Desktop/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-84-generic'
Makefile:1350: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

.

After that, I have found another way to approach the problem, using files from [this](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux) site and following [this](http://cfyves.com/2015/03/17/how-to-install-d-link-dwa-182-wireless-ac1200-dual-band-usb-adapter-on-linux-ubuntu/) guide. After running `make` I received the following list of errors

```
/home/szymon/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:6001:2: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
  .del_station = cfg80211_rtw_del_station,
  ^
/home/szymon/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:6001:2: error: (near initialization for ‘rtw_cfg80211_ops.del_station’) [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/home/szymon/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/szymon/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o] Error 1
Makefile:1395: recipe for target '_module_/home/szymon/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/szymon/Desktop/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-84-generic'
Makefile:1584: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

.

As you can see, they look pretty similar. To be honest, I have no idea how should I proceed now... I tried looking up the errors, but didn't succeed. To complete the question I'm adding two results about the adapter

```
lsusb
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2001:3315 D-Link Corp.

sudo lshw -C network
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 11
       serial: 14:dd:a9:dc:52:02
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

.

I don't know if that's relevant, but when I click on the internet connection icon in the Ubuntu upper-right toolbar, there is `RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller` option visible (displayed in grey, without way to "interact" with it), followed by `disconnected`.

As you can see I am totally Ubuntu-noob and would really appreciate your help. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: [That's](http://support.dlink.ca/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-182) the website that I downloaded the drivers from. I'm sure that they were the correct ones (version C)

Answer (score 1):

## Setup Wireless USB (DWA-182 rev.C) On Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 thru 20.04

Make sure USB wireless device not inserted

1. Update the system:
   `$ sudo apt update`
2. Install required packages:
   `$ sudo apt install git && build-essential`
3. Download the driver:
   `$ sudo git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au`
4. Go to the directory:
   `$ cd rtl8812au`
5. Do the next commands consecutively:
   `$ sudo make clean`
   `$ sudo make`
   `$ sudo make uninstall`
   `$ sudo make install`

Reboot and insert USB wireless stick

-Persists reboots
-Works with dlink dwa-182 and linksys WUSB6300

Comment: This answer is useful, thanks very much. with dwa-182 on ubuntu 18.04