# Will ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS work on my macbook?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, mac

I can run it from the usb drive, but it can't find the network adapter. Would it be easier to set up and solve this problem after installing the OS on my machine, or what? I would like to dual boot ubuntu and mac mojave if it isn't too time consuming

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) and [My WiFi adapter is not working at all, how to troubleshoot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/)

Comment: if it can't find the network adapter from the usb it won't when fully installed either. you either need a newer version of ubuntu or to find the necessary driver. what is your exact mac model (not "macmini or "mac pro") so that we may find out exactly what network card it is equiped with.

Comment: It's a macbook air 13", early 2015, intel core i5 processor running macOS mojave 10.14.5

Comment: serial number is CO2TMOU8H3QD

Comment: looking for the network card info now

Comment: Card Type: AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x117)
  Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.2 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.8)
  MAC Address: d4:61:9d:0f:da:fc
  Locale: FCC
  Country Code: US
  Supported PHY Modes: 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac
  Supported Channels: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140, 144, 149, 153, 157, 161, 165

Comment: Possible duploiicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/)

Comment: The *easiest* way to solve is to install Ubuntu while plugged into a a wired network, then solve the BCM wireless driver after install. You generally need network access to download BCM drivers.

Comment: BTW, by using virtualization as suggested in my answer below, I have no network driver issues.  I'm presently running an 18.04 VM on my Macbook with VirtualBox and the networking is 100% straight.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm reading your question as wanting to run Linux on your Mac, rather than setting up a dual-boot.**

I'd suggest ***virtualization*** in lieu of configuring a dual-boot if your goal is just to run Linux on your Mac OSX system. That's what myself and many others Linux folks with Macs do.  VirtualBox is a popular option that's free and proven to work well on a Mac.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

### Linux on a Mac: Virtualization versus Dual-Booting

1. VirtualBox is easy to setup and can be upgraded in-place.
2. You can side-step driver issues like you're experiencing: I'm running 18.04 as a VM on my own MacBook with VirtualBox and its' networking is straight; no driver problems.
3. Both OSX and Linux Operating Systems can be run concurrently.  You do not need to reboot into different OS which is really interruptive.
4. No need to allocate dedicated partitioned space for another OS which would be the case in a dual-boot.  Using VirtualBox you can just create VMs from available free disk space on your Mac.  If you get tight on space for your Mac, you can free some up by deleting the VM; not so easy with a dual boot.
5. VM's can be backedup with Time Machine as any other file. Note though they should not be running during the backup however.
6. You can migrate your Linux VMs to a new Mac as a file.  I think I've migrated the same VM now to 3 different Macs by this point

### Networking

In respect to network connectivity- *shouldn't have any driver issues now* -  you have a choice of bridging or NAT'ing. If you're not a networking guru, bridging is easy to setup.

Anyhoo, hope this helps you integrate ***Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*** into your Mac OSX environment-

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 VirtualBox on OSX Mojave]

Comment: Great, thanks. I will try your suggestion when I get a chance

Comment: No worries bud. I think you'll find VirtualBox a great addition to your Mac.

Comment: @ErikD Did you get a chance to try the solution I proposed using VirtualBox?