# Wifi not working [ No wifi adpater found ubuntu 18.04 ]

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I found many similar questions and followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot#:%7E:text=In%20case%20you%20have%20trouble,Unplug%20the%20device.&text=You%27re%20hitting%20a%20hardware,point%20%2D%20fix%20USB%20communication%20first.) one. As per the accepted answer, in case the status of wireless interface listed as `*-network UNCLAIMED`, I should follow the steps to install new drivers. On heading over [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/47506/88802), under additional drivers section, I don't see any driver recommendation instead it shows [image: this] . Now how should I proceed? None of the answer in the last link solves this.

Machine is dual boot, but on windows side, `wifi` is working.

**UPDATE:** Lucky or Unlucky, can't decide. Maybe lucky if it is solved forever. And Today it happened again. Here are the result of `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

*WORKING:* *(recorded yesterday when it was working)*

```
user@user-VivoBook-ASUS-Laptop-X505ZA-X505ZA:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for user: 
[   11.035571] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   13.010450] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.9f0a2d68.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   14.243303] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8265, REV=0x230
[   14.301378] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: 90:78:41:15:35:c9
[   14.376233] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   14.567117] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
```

*NOT WORKING* *(recorded just now)*

```
user@user-VivoBook-ASUS-Laptop-X505ZA-X505ZA:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for user: 
[   12.328948] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   12.402564] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Comment: Let's have a look at the log. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Today when I turned on the laptop, its wifi is working. I can connect to the wifi network and use it.  This is not the first time I encountered this issue, it happens always. Yesterday when it wasn't working, I restarted the machine at least 10 times, and still, it reported the issue of not being able to find the wifi adapter. But today wifi is there. I'm worried I will be encountering this problem again. @chili555 Does the output log of the above command will help right now. I've to mitigate this issue forever.

Comment: I don't know if the log readings taken when the wifi is working will show us any useful clues. I prefer those taken when it is not working. However, why not capture both? If the results are lengthy, post then here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Please annotate each as WORKING and NOT WORKING.

Comment: @chili555 added the results.

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: yes, it is. I've already added this in question.

Comment: Did you disable Fast Boot?

Comment: @chili555 Yes, It's working now. Thanks. I don't know if it's gone forever or it will happen again . You write it as answer and take the  credit.  I've another `ubuntu` machine(dual boot) with same problem. but from last 6-7 months  i've not been able to use the ubuntu OS on that bcoz of the wifi problem. `ubuntu 19.10` or `19.04` is installed on that and I'm unable to run any update command on terminal to upgrade it to `20 LTS` version.  The only difference is as on this machine i was able to see `wifi` symbol  on a few or several restarts but on that this was never the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> iwlwifi: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -110

Error -110 often suggests that, in a dual-boot system, Windows has not completely shut down the wireless device in order to allow it to boot quite quickly.  Since Windows still has at least partial control of the wireless device, it is not fully available to Ubuntu. Please see: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Please reboot into Windows and disable Fast Boot. Reboot into Ubuntu and I suspect that the Error -110 messages will be gone and that the wireless will now be working.