# wifi is not working (not showing ) and bluetooth is not found (showing plug a dongle to use a bluetooth) ubuntu 22.04..3 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth, internet

I have dell Inspiron 7501 laptop and only have ubuntu installed in it .
I am sure that i have bluetooth and wifi adapters in there but i dont know why it is not working . it is a fresh install of ubuntu.
Any suggestions ,advice would be appreciated . if you need any output please ask.

my wireless-info can be found here https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/n82WnG69pn/

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the output of the `wireless-info` script from https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/1004020

Comment: @DanielT edited my question with wireless info

Comment: What is the exact problem with your WiFi? It looks fine: `inet 192.168.1.7` `GENERAL.STATE: 100 (connected)` `SSID HAR HAR MAHADEV IN-USE yes`

Comment: @DanielT That is because i am using plug in usb dongle for using wifi for now. But my built in wifi in laptop is not showing. Also bluetooth is not showing/working . Right now i am using external usb wifi for internet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wifi not working \[ No wifi adpater found ubuntu 18.04 \]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340853/wifi-not-working-no-wifi-adpater-found-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: I found the problem: "iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -110". Make sure Windows is not messing up your WiFi adapter

Comment: @DanielT my system only have ubuntu in single boot.

Comment: Does the problem also occur on the Ubuntu 23.10 LiveUSB, which uses newer firmware?

Comment: @DanielT i have to check it. anything else that i could do now?

Comment: You could look in BIOS for settings related to power or WiFi. You could also remove the battery, hold the power button down for 1 minute, then reboot and try again

Comment: @DanielT okay i will try all these things and will revert back to you in a day . Thank You

Comment: @DanielT i didnt tried any of these thing . But something strange happened this morning when i started my laptop freshly this morning my wifi and bluetooth both were running fine , but then when i closed the lid and opened it back wifi and bluetooth were gone ,like before.